# compileClassPAth errors when trying to add library in android studio

Tags: android, gradle

I tried adding a library into my android studio project but it is giving me the following errors:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :libraries:MultipleImagePick-master.


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :libraries:MultipleImagePick-master.


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :libraries:MultipleImagePick-master.


Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :libraries:MultipleImagePick-master.



Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :libraries:MultipleImagePick-master.
```

I basically created a directory within my project named 'libraries' and pasted the library whici is named MultipleImagePick-master.

I then included this in my settings gradle:

```
include ':libraries:MultipleImagePick-master'
```

I then added the dependency module for this in the the project and whilst it tried to do the build then I got those failures. Below are both my gradle.build files:

app gradle build:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.mima.iloveyou"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':libraries:MultipleImagePick-master')
}
```

Project gradle build:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the version of ConstraintLayout Library back to 1.1.1

```
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app level gradle try this

```
implementation project(path: ':libraries:MultipleImagePick-master', configuration: 'default')
```

Comment: Gives me same errors in th build and for the sync it states: Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'implementation' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :libraries:MultipleImagePick-master.